# Extending method chaining IEnumerable with Add..If

Tags: c#, iterator, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension (method chaining) for playing around a bit.

What I made work is an extension to add an item to the list (what is pretty easy):

```
IEnumerable<int> myList = originalList.Add(12);
```

What I now want to do is:

```
IEnumerable<int> myList = originalList.Add(12).If((list, @new) => !list.Contains(@new));
```

What it should do:
If the `originalList` doesn't already contain `@new` (12), then it may not add it to the list.
If the `If`-sequence is not added, the element gets added.

So this is my code:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IAddEnumerable<T> Add<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, T element)
        => new AddEnumerable<T>(@this, element);
    
}

public interface IAddEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> If(Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> expression);
}
            
internal class AddEnumerable<T> : IAddEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _sequence;
    private readonly T _elementToAdd;

    private bool _added;

    public AddEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> sequence, T elementToAdd)
    {
        _sequence = sequence;
        _elementToAdd = elementToAdd;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> If(Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> expression)
    {
        _added = true;

        if (expression(_sequence,_elementToAdd))
            _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);

        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_added) 
            return _sequence.GetEnumerator();

        _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);
        _added = true;

        return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
    }
            
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_added) 
            return _sequence.GetEnumerator();

        _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);
        _added = true;

        return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

It works, but I wanted to ask, if there are any problems that could come up with, or if there is something I could do better.

Comment: The `AddEnumerable` constructors feels really strange. What's the sole purpose of the `_elementToAdd` private field?

Comment: @PeterCsala this is the element/item that gets added whether the condition in `If` is true, or there is no `If`.

Comment: It still feels strange. You can use it with or without the `If` builder method. That's why the complexity goes into `GetEnumerator` methods. You have code duplication because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the idea - but have the following comments:

```
  var originalList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
  IEnumerable<int> myList = originalList.Add(12).If((list, item) => !list.Contains(item));
```

If the `originalList` is defined explicit as something that implements `ICollection`, then you get a compiler error saying: "`Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'`", because `Add()` is already a method returning `void`.

---

> ```
>     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
>     {
>         if (_added) 
>             return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
>
>         _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);
>         _added = true;
>
>         return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
>     }
>             
>     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>     {
>         if (_added) 
>             return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
>
>         _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);
>         _added = true;
>
>         return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
>     }
> ```

Don't repeat code - the second method can call the first:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  return GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

> ```
> public interface IAddEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
> {
>     IEnumerable<T> If(Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> expression);
> }
> ```

By renaming this interface you could extend its usability to for instance a sequence like:

```
data.Remove(12).If(<predicate>);
```

Maybe `IPredicate` or something like that.

---

Although I know that `@new`, `@this` etc. are valid variable names, I personally always avoid them, because they distract the reading. I have never been in a situation where it was unavoidable to use them.

---

I understand, that you want a fluid approach, and therefore define the `If` method separately, but I think, I would concatenate the behavior to a single function like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AddIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T element, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> predicate)
{
  return predicate(source, element) ? source.AddItem(element) : source;
}
```

---

An idea came to my mind: Because you return `this` from `If()`, I think, you can avoid the repetitive code in there by saving the predicate and then handle everything in `GetEnumerator()`:

```
  internal class AddEnumerable<T> : IAddEnumerable<T>
  {
    private IEnumerable<T> _sequence;
    private readonly T _elementToAdd;
    private Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> _expression;

    private bool _added;

    public AddEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> sequence, T elementToAdd)
    {
      _sequence = sequence;
      _elementToAdd = elementToAdd;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> If(Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> expression)
    {
      _expression = expression;
      return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
      if (_added)
        return _sequence.GetEnumerator();

      if (_expression == null || _expression(_sequence, _elementToAdd))
      {
        _sequence = _sequence.AddItem(_elementToAdd);
      }
      _added = true;

      return _sequence.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great. Yep, I named the method `AddE` (due to `Add` already exists) in my file and renamed it for posting here - didn't think about anymore. I only (and always) use `@this` for extension-methods, otherwise i'm trying to avoid those. Thanks for review and tipps!